# andand chain not working properly

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, andand

im trying to refactor this code of mine:

```
test_cases.select{ |x| x.script && x.script.versions && !x.script.versions.empty? }
```

and use the andand gem. Basic usage just tells us that we substitute andand to the &&(thus the name) so i tried this:

```
test_cases.select{ |x| !x.andand.script.andand.script_versions.andand.empty? }
```

but it seems it is NOT-ing the whole statement(i just realized this now while writing the question)

Does this mean I have to separate the empty? clause? Is there an andand function that checks for not(but only the last one?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually used this clause and it works:

```
test_cases.map{ |x| x.script.andand.versions && !x.script.versions.empty? }.none?
```

only one andand call and used map instead of select

Answer (score 0):

You could always do

```
test_cases.select{ |x| x.andand.script.andand.script_version } unless x.empty?
```

On the topic of `andand`: while we use it in our project and I generally quite like it, I found that spurious use of `andand` can hide problems that should be properly addressed. Like many good tools it has to be used with caution.

Answer (score 0):

When `x` is not `nil` it works well, I guess. The problem is when `x` is `nil` because `...empty?` returns also `nil`, and `!nil` -> `true`. Then this `x` is wrongly selected. I'd propose an explicit check of the boolean value:

```
 test_cases.select { |x| x.andand.script.andand.versions.andand.empty? == false }
```

Or probably better use blank/present without a last *andand*:

```
 test_cases.select { |x| x.andand.script.andand.versions.present? }
 test_cases.reject { |x| x.andand.script.andand.versions.blank? }
```

Note: it's not related with the problem here, but I prefer Ick's *maybe* over *andand*, as only `nil` is treated as "void" (`false` is a legitimate value which I think should not be proxied).